# Reversing row values in a panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i'm having a mind wipe, i cannot for the life of me figure out a simple way of reversing this input to the output, any help would be appreciated.

input:

| level1 | level2 | level3 | level4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | NaN |
| 2 | 1 | NaN | NaN |

output:

| level1 | level2 | level3 | level4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | NaN |
| 1 | 2 | NaN | NaN |

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does [Reverse Row Values in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633212/reverse-row-values-in-pandas-dataframe) help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way, using reindexing:

```
(df
 .apply(lambda s: s.dropna()[::-1].reset_index(drop=True), axis=1)
 .reindex(columns=range(df.shape[1]))
 .set_axis(df.columns, axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
   level1  level2  level3  level4
0     1.0     2.0     4.0     NaN
1     1.0     2.0     NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the results for which you are looking

```
df.rank(axis = 1, ascending = False)
```

You will need to work with the results though if you have to remove the float value since there are NaN in your data, but that should be easier to do